# Unit Test orEmpty() method Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin

I am writing Junit Test case but in Jacoco code coverage I am not able o cover this line ***uri.host.orEmpty()***
How to write unit test case for ***uri.host.orEmpty()***
I wrote this case but it didn't work

```
var url = "https://abc.co.jp/app/#/dashboard"
        val uri = URLUtil.getHostName(url)
        uri shouldBe "abc.co.jp"

        url = "https://"
        URLUtil.getHostName(url) shouldBe ""
```

[image]

Comment: Check `orEmpty()` definition . Its returns `this ?: ""` . i.e empty String if null or `String` itself. You can `assert` for both cases during test .

Comment: i used this but didnt work :
var url = "https://abc.co.jp/app/#/dashboard"
        val uri = URLUtil.getHostName(url)
        uri shouldBe "abc.co.jp"

        url = "https://"
        URLUtil.getHostName(url) shouldBe ""

Answer (score 0):

Just do `host?:""` instead of calling a `function`, code coverage can be ignored on library functions, but if you want to cover most of it do below

```
fun getHostName(url: String): String{
    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
    return uri.host?:""
}
```

Comment: I dont want to change much code but same issue happening on or condition, Jacoco can not cover this line too
 return it.contains("/abc) || it.contains("/webview")